# Naming Conflict in C++: How to access a struct member called "class"

Tags: c++, c, struct, naming-conventions

I came across a naming problem while working with the xlib library:

I'm using a struct which has a member called "class". I assume this library is mostly used in plain C programs. So there's no problem.

But I'm programming in C++ and here the name "class" is a keyword and cannot be used to denote variables. So, if I'm accessing the struct via

`myvariable = mystruct->class;`

I'm getting the error:

`expected unqualified-id before ‘class’`

Given that I cannot change the struct itself, how can I access this struct member despite the naming conflict?

Comment: <**dirty**> You could probably define a structure with the same layout, but with a different name for the class member, then cast the libraries struct to your duplicate and access the variable that way, with it's other name... `MyStruct *f=(MyStruct*)mystruct; myvariable = f->myNewClassName;`

Comment: `Xlib.h` takes care of this issue (and a similar issue with `XColormapEvent.new`) with some macro mangling. Are you having trouble with your own struct, a third party struct, or an XLib struct?

Comment: It's an xlib struct ("Visual"). And you're right, it turns out xlib has a marco to solve this problem. That's what I'm using now. But this issue might also be of general interest for other C libraries.

Comment: @forsvarir: dirty but legal. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2342.htm for an extensive discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that you're using XLib. I can only find two places in my `Xlib.h` where `class` is used as a structure member: `Visual` and `XWindowAttributes`. In both cases, the offending member is wrapped like this:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus)
    int c_class;
#else
    int class;
#endif
```

Similar hackery appears in `XColormapEvent` to take care of the `new` member.

So you should be fine unless your C++ compiler isn't defining any of the necessary macros; but that would also break the usual `extern "C" { ... }` wrappers as well so the problem is most likely elsewhere. If you're using a struct that isn't part of the standard XLib then you should apply the above hack by hand and have a stern discussion with the library's author (and if that's you then angrily talk to yourself for a bit and we'll pretend not to listen).

If you are having trouble with the XLib structs, then try using the C++ version of the member names:

```
myvariable = mystruct->c_class;
mynew      = ev->c_new;
```

Comment: +1: on the assumption that you haven't missed something this is the right fix, use the C++ version of the name :-) If I was XLib I'd want to just call the member something different in both C and C++. I guess they need to maintain compatibility in C with a version of the API that they published before they supported C++ at all, or some such.

Comment: @Steve: I did check the header file. The "c_" silliness smells like a committee's solution to the problem of C++ compatibility while maintaining backwards compatibility with all the existing C code.

Comment: Turns out you're right, the questioner says it's `Visual`. By "haven't missed something", I was just hedging my bets - I don't know Xlib, so I didn't know whether there was some other header file elsewhere with another `class` data member that hadn't got this treatment. But even if there is, it doesn't matter, you gave the right fix for the questioner.

Comment: @Steve: I haven't touched X programming in over a decade but experience (i.e. making mistaeks) is a great teacher.

Comment: This solution was already mentioned earlier in a comment on my post. In fact, this is how I solved it. Anyways, many thanks for the explicit solution!

Answer (score 19):

> Given that I cannot change the struct itself, how can I access this struct member despite the naming conflict?

Maybe you can rename it using a #define, something like

```
#define class xclass
#include "header.h"
#undef class

// ...

myvariable = mystruct->xclass;
```

Comment: +1:  This is the most straightforward and widely supported means of addressing the issue.

Comment: @wallyk, provided that if "header.h" is only a `C` header file.

Comment: @iammilind, that can be asumed if it includes a struct with a member called "class".

Comment: This is the solution I used. Straighforward and simple.

Comment: Technically an ODR violation, though, unlike forsvarir's solution (in comment)

Answer (score 14):

`class` is a keyword in C++. You cannot use it as a variable.

If you want to still access it than you can code that part in C and then compile it with c compiler:

```
typedef struct foo {
    bar class;
} foo;

bar *getClassPtr(foo *p) { return &(p->class); }
```

Include that part in your C++ code using,

```
extern "C" {
   bar *getClassPtr(foo *);
}
bar &getClass(foo &s) { return *getClassPtr(&s); }
```

You might also want const versions.

You still can't include the struct definition in your C++ code, so you may have to wrap the other members of `foo` in the same way. Unless link-time optimization can inline `getClassPtr`, there's some overhead in the call, compared with accessing the struct member directly from C++. Normally this will be negligible, but it's worth knowing about.

You may want to find info about [extern "C"](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1143/).

Comment: This answer looks like only c++ standard compliant (without a need to use extensions)

Comment: Did you actually try that?  I believe `extern "C"` changes calling convention and/or mangling, but the code inside that block still needs to be valid C++.

Comment: I don't understand this. `extern "C"` doesn't compile as C, and `mystruct->class` doesn't compile as C++, so where does this code snippet go? [Edit: ah, VJo broke it. What should happen is that a C file should contain `somevariable myvariable = mystruct->class;`, or better `struct somevariable *getClass(struct somestruct *p) { return &(p->class); }`, and then the C++ program should contain `extern "C" { somevariable myvariable; somevariable *getClass(somestruct *); }`.]

Comment: @Steve Jessop, here intention was to keep `class` variable related code in `.c` files and keeping its interfaces visible to `C++`, using `extern "C"`. So, I don't suggest to use `class` inside the `.cpp` file at all.

Comment: @iammilind: yep, I see now that it's VJo's code not yours. Would you like to edit the answer to something you *would* suggest, or shall I do what VJo did, go right ahead and put words in your mouth, and edit in my suggestion? :-)

Comment: @Tony You are correct. The code will still be compiled as C++ under a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Class is a reserved keyword in C++ and cannot be used as a variable name. You will have to rename the variable.

Comment: I think he knows that already. He's asking if there is a way around it. But most certainly there isn't.

Comment: I know that it's a keyword. Assuming I cannot rename the struct's members. Is there no way to access it anyway? (Like temporarily disable a certain C++ keyword?)

Comment: -1, the poster already knows this, he is looking for a workaround. Read the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

In VC++, you can use Microsoft extension keyword: [__identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzc8ytsz.aspx)

```
int __identifier(float);
__identifier(float) = 10.4f;
```

MSDN says it is applicable for /clr (Managed C++) only, but that's not true. It existed even in VC6

Answer (score 0):

As `class` is a keyword in C++, the compiler will complain if you use it

Maybe you could create a "wrapper" struct (in C) that allows to access your faulty structure, something like

```
typedef struct Wrapper_ {
    faultyStruct * mystruct ;
    faultyStructClass * cls ;
} Wrapper ;

Wrapper wrap(faultyStruct * s) {
    Wrapper w = {s, &(s->class) } ;
}
```

Compile this file with your C compiler and use it in your C++ code through `extern "C"`

You can also use preprocessor to re-define `class` (but I'm not sure wether it is legal to #define C++ keywords

Comment: "I'm not sure wether it is legal to #define C++ keywords" - it's not legal, but in practice your preprocessor doesn't know or care whether something's a C++ keyword or not, so in practice it will work. Hacktastic.

Comment: it's undefined behavior to `#define` most keywords (for some of them, it's ill-formed and diagnosed). So you should be fine - no real compiler will error out because there's not really a reason to.